# ¿Como mostrar un ListView con contenido de imagenes y texto?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

En la base de datos tengo registrado una imagen y nombre, el cual quiero mostrar esa imagen y su nombre en un ListView, pero no le logrado conseguir que se muestre la lista los datos ya mencionados, estoy trabajado con un web service, ya que no he trabajo con imágenes solo con datos,o tal vez en el adapter este haciendo mal algún código, ya que me sale un error tal como se muestra en la captura, ya que el error me sale desde el adapter algo me este faltando.

**Adapter.java**

```
public class AdapterUbicacionMex extends ArrayAdapter<EstadoMexico> {

  Context context;
  List<EstadoMexico> ubicacionList;
  List<EstadoMexico> listaOriginal;

   public AdapterUbicacionMex(@NonNull Context context,List<EstadoMexico> ubicacionList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_ubicamexico,ubicacionList);
    this.context = context;
    this.ubicacionList = ubicacionList;

    this.listaOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
    listaOriginal.addAll(ubicacionList);
   }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_ubicamexico,null, true);

    TextView TVNombre = vista.findViewById(R.id.nombre_ubicacion);
    ImageView IMImagen = vista.findViewById(R.id.imagenViewUbicacion);

    TVNombre.setText(ubicacionList.get(position).getNombre());
    IMImagen.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(ubicacionList.get(position).getImagenMexico()));

    return vista;
    }
   }
```

**Lista_ubicacionMex.java**

```
  public class Lista_UbicacionMex extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    AdapterUbicacionMex ubicacionmexAdapter;

    FloatingActionButton botonFlotante;

    public static ArrayList<EstadoMexico> estadoMexicoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

   private static final String Url ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/listaUbicaMex.php";

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista__ubicacion_mex);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ubicación");

    botonFlotante = findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_UbicaMex);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.id_listView_producEA);

    ubicacionmexAdapter = new AdapterUbicacionMex(this,estadoMexicoArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(ubicacionmexAdapter);

    mostrarLista();
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id== android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
  public void mostrarLista(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            estadoMexicoArrayList.clear();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("t_imagen_estado_mexico");

                if (sucess.equals("1")){
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String imagenMexico = object.getString("imagenMexico");
                        String nombre = object.getString("nombre");


                        EstadoMexico estadoMexico = new EstadoMexico();
                        estadoMexico.setImagenMexico(imagenMexico);
                        estadoMexico.setNombre(nombre);


                        estadoMexicoArrayList.add(estadoMexico);
                        ubicacionmexAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Lista_UbicacionMex.this, error.getMessage(),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
     }
    }
```

**Base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter()

Comment: Hola. Se agradece que pongas los mensajes de error como texto, no como imagen, pues es más fácil de leer el texto. Por lo pronto, lo que dice el mensaje de error es que `listView` es nulo. ¿Puedes mostrar el XML donde se supone que está tu ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error,

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter()

El problema indica que dentro de tu layout `activity_lista__ubicacion_mex.xml` no se encuentra el `ListView` con id `id_listView_producEA`, debes agregarlo ahí.

Comment: Ohh si ya vi donde esta el error y ya lo corregí, solo que salen otros detalles

Comment: Te voy dar como buena respuesta, voy a formular la otra pregunta en un rato mas.

Comment: Si @Miguel excelente, te ayudo también